# Does a PHP file work in a NODE JS Container?

Tags: php, html, node.js

I'm new to PHP, and building an app in a NODE JS container on Nitrous.  We are adding a php backend Mandrill email form.  Do PHP files work on Node JS containers?  Sorry for the newbie question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node runs javascript. In order to run PHP, you'll need a web server capable of running php such as nginx + fpm or apache + mod_php. Here are the official getting started docs on Nitrous + PHP: https://www.nitrous.io/stacks/php/.